# Tangent plane perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the point on the surface $z=x^3-xy$ $\ $ which has tangent plane perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$ and write down the Cartesian equation for this tangent plane.

I'm a bit confused here. How do I find a plane perpendicular to a point? Am I on the right track? Or is the question asking something else?

Answer given is $x+y+z=2$

Comment: That is a vector not a point in this case.

Comment: Ahhh that explains it. All good now, thanks.